# Jade - Is it possible to add to a block override?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, pug

Say I have this top level template (_main.jade):

```
html
    head
        title test
    body
        block content
```

And then I have this second level template (_project.jade) that I want to add content to what it gets from the last level:

```
extends _main.jade

block content
    // somehow include content from final level here.
    p some extra content that gets appended to the project content.
```

And then the final level (myProject.jade):

```
extends _project.jade

block content
    p this is the content for my project.
```

To my understanding, I can just add another block definition in _project.jade under 'block content' with 'block projectContent' or something, but it would be nice if I could just use my block keyword 'content' everywhere.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. I just ended up using a different block name in the second level template.

```
extends _main.jade

block content
    // include content from final level here.
    block projectContent
    p some extra content that gets appended to the project content.
```